# Formatting string to string Date Format .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Given a string value eg "03252013" I need to convert this string to be in this format "DDMMYYYY".
Which function do you use? The result should be "25032013"

```
string myTestDate="03252013";
string resultDate=??
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` method. Then use `ToString` to convert to appropriate format.

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03252013", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var result = dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy"); //25032013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myTestDate, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply parse then re-format:

```
string input = "03252013"
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string resultDate = date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your needs really are that simple I would consider just switching the values around...

```
string input = "03252013";
string output = input.Substring(2, 2) + input.Substring(0, 2) + input.Substring(4, 4);
```

...dont forget to validate the input before using substring (checking the length is 8 will probably be enough)

NOTE: If it is likely that your input or output formats will change then it would be more ideal to do the DateTime.Parse technique as suggested by many others. But if this is really the only situations then this method should provide better performance... slightly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You, can use the Help of following code part to convert.

```
string resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(myTestDate, "MMDDYYYY", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("DDMMYYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
`resultDate = DateTime.Parse(myTestDate,"d").toString();`
"d" is a format provider that says to farmat the date like this: DD/MM/YYYY